# Assignment operator, identical statements

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

This is a dumb question but I'm stumped. Are the following two C++ statements identical?

```
regWages = regPay + overTime;
regPay + overTime = regWages;
```

Comment: If in doubt, always try compiling it in a current standard compiler.  As an experiment I tried the second line (e.g. not expecting much).  And the compiler says, "expression is not assignable."  This is from a C++11 compiler based on the CLang++ 3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. One is valid, the other isn't. (Maybe.*)

You can generally only assign to *lvalues*, which are, tautologically, things you can assign to. The result of an arithmetic expression usually isn't something you can assign to.

More simply: `a = 1 + 2` is OK, but `1 + 2 = a` is not. You can give `a` a value, but you cannot give the result of an addition of integers a value.

Assignment in C++ is a state change. It is very different from the mathematical concept of "equations". An assignment in C++ is more like a *definition* in mathematics, but unlike in maths you can reassign values to existing objects.

<sub>*) Operator overloading complicates the picture a bit.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To solve your doubt, you should understand ome import concept: [Lvalues and Rvalues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

In your code, `regWages = regPay + overTime;` is right, because if the variable `regWages` is Lvalues, it is a non-temporary object and you can do `=` operation.

`regPay + overTime = regWages;` is wrong, because of the result of `regPay + overTime` is Rvalues, just a temporary variable, you can't do `=` operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is funny but the both operators can be valid depending of the type definition of the objects.

```
regWages = regPay + overTime;
regPay + overTime = regWages;
```

However semantically they are different, The assignment operator is not symmetric.